# Java 1.8 with Mockito 1.9.5 gives compile errors

Tags: java, mockito

After switching to Java 1.8. JDK some of my test classes fail to compile.
Example of implementation class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ImplClass {

    public <T> Future<T> executeTask(final Callable<T> task) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the test class with Mockito:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.junit.Before;

public class TestClass {

    private ImplClass implClassMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        implClassMock = mock(ImplClass.class);
        when(implClassMock.executeTask(any(Callable.class))).thenReturn(null);
    }
}
```

I get the error message: `The method executeTask(Callable<T>) in the type ImplClass is not applicable for the arguments (Callable)`

Switching back to java compiler 1.7 everything is fine.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why should the ImplClass be generic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since java 8, the [compiler type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) have been greatly improved.

Now you could remove the class parameter from the matcher without any compilation warning:

```
when(implClassMock.executeTask(any())).thenReturn(null);
```

---

Note: i have the same compiler failure but only with eclipse. A bug may be ?

Comment: This seems to be indeed the case, `javac` is compiling this just fine. I have not yet confirmed it on Eclipse, but it is not the first time I have seen bugs in the Eclipse compiler, far from it...
Now I only trust `javac`

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to mention that I use eclipse.

Comment: It is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444334 The bug is fixed in JDT 4.4 . Eclipse Mars 4.5

Comment: @JulienCarsique i have not investigated but the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26372875/1594933) say it is another bug.

Comment: @gontard (430987) which as been confirmed as duplicate of 444334.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this is caused by javac being more flexible than what JLS requires. Eclipse compiler with compliance level of 1.8 is more strict: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430987

The answer by @gontard works in most cases but if the method that you are stubbing has overrides with different parameter types javac will get confused. For example ExecutorService.submit() takes both Callable and Runnable as parameters, you can't mock it with when(executor.submit(any())).then(...) as it is ambiguous. But explicitly parametrizing the type like this will keep both eclipse and javac compilers happy:

```
when(executor.<Object>submit(any(Callable.class)).then(...)
```

Comment: AspectJ compiler has the same issue. I worked around it by adding a cast: `when( executorService.submit( (Callable<Object>)any( Callable.class ) ) ).thenReturn( future );`