# Mockito Java 8 compilation errors

Tags: java-8, mockito

I just moved to Java 8 and I am getting some compilation errors that I don't really understand how to overcome.

The following code does not compile:

```
Mockito.when(
    jdbcTemplate.query(Mockito.eq(expectedQuery1),
        Mockito.any(ResultSetExtractor.class))).thenReturn(mockReturn1);
```

With error:

```
The method query(String, ResultSetExtractor<T>) in the type JdbcTemplate is not 
applicable for the arguments (String, ResultSetExtractor)
```

I have tried another approach from [Java 1.8 with Mockito 1.9.5 gives compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675745/java-1-8-with-mockito-1-9-5-gives-compile-errors):

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(Mockito.eq(expectedQuery1), Mockito.any()))
    .thenReturn(mockReturn1);
```

now I am getting the following error:

```
The method when(T) in the type Mockito is not applicable for the arguments (void)
```

how exactly does this supposed to work and why doesn't it work in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a type witness to help the Eclipse compiler figure it all out:

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(Mockito.eq(expectedQuery1),
        Mockito.<ResultSetExtractor<TYPE>> any())).thenReturn(mockReturn1);
```

Ensure you replace `TYPE` with the type of `mockReturn1`. E.g.

```
String mockReturn1 = "result";

Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(Mockito.eq(expectedQuery1),
        Mockito.<ResultSetExtractor<String>> any())).thenReturn(mockReturn1);
```

I expect the Oracle Java 8 compiler could figure this out itself, due to its improved type inference capabilities.

Comment: Sure, you can do this when `any()` is called without a parameter.  But the original question primarily asks about invoking `any()` ***with*** a parameter.  You cannot specify a generic argument to `any()` which disagrees with the type of the parameter that you pass to it.  You cannot do `Mockito.<X<Y>>any( X.class )`.

Comment: @MikeNakis I don't really understand the point you're making. The OP is trying to mock a suitable response to a call to `query()`. In order to be able to return a type `T`, he must be matching a call with a `ResultSetExtractor<T>` (or perhaps `ResultSetExtractor<? super T>`).

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are passing mockito `ResultSetExtractor.class`, which is of type `Class<ResultSetExtractor>`, but this is incorrect, because it is expecting a `Class<ResultSetExtractor<T>>`.

To overcome this problem, define a method as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "rawtypes" )
public static <T> Class<T> uncheckedClassCast( Class clazz )
{
    if( clazz == null )
        return null;
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    Class<T> result = (Class<T>)clazz;
    return result;
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
Class<ResultSetExtractor<T>> resultSetExtractorClass =
    uncheckedClassCast( ResultSetExtractor.class );
```

Then, in your calls to mockito (or anything else) use `resultSetExtractorClass` instead of `ResultSetExtractor.class`.

Comment: There is no need to do an unchecked cast here. See my answer for the correct approach using type witnesses. (Although I think it's only the Eclipse compiler that is having a problem here).

Comment: I wouldent downvote this answer. even though Duncan's answer is more elegant, I am sure your answer will help people that come across problems with mockito and java 8 and needs a bit more complex solution.

Comment: @Gleeb Actually, my answer applies to any situation where you have a similar issue, not just this specific issue with mockito.

Comment: @Gleeb the downvote that my answer received is probably Duncan following item #2 from this advice: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/175648 which many consider ethically objectionable.  I could have done the same to Duncan, but I did not.

Comment: upvoted you to sattle this like friends :) thanks for the help